# Handling multiple certificates with Spring Webservices

Tags: web-services, spring, soap, spring-ws, ws-security

I have a client that is sending SOAP message to a Spring Web Services endpoint that I created. The message is signed and encrypted and I am successfully decrypting the message, and signing/encrypting my response using our respective public/private keys. I am doing this by using security interceptors (wss4j) configured in the application context xml. The problem is, it seems that with this configuration, I can only use one certificate from the client. Now, the client wants to send the same request, but from two different systems simultaneously, so they will be using two certificates. My question is, is there a way/strategy to build some intelligence into my endpoint to determine which certificate based on the message received? Can I look at the signature in the soap header? Can I configure this with interceptors in the app context or will I need another approach?